# How-to tilt the face to the right or left side given a photo that the face is facing forward?

Tags: images, image-editing

Is it possible? Are there any software(s) (possibly free ones if any) that can perform such photo edit?

Comment: Did you want to rotate the whole image by a few degrees? Most image editors can do that (e.g. Picasa "straighten")

Comment: No, I do not wish to rotate the whole image. I just want to rotate that face on the image by a few degrees.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in most photo-editing software such as Photoshop ($$$) or Gimp (Free) but it isn't as simple as you might want. When you rotate a face you will have some gaps left behind (unless the face is perfectly circular, which is rare) you need to fill these gaps from similar nearby areas.

- select the face  (use edge detection or manual outline tracing)
- rotate the selection (you may need to cut and paste first)
- fill in the gaps (zoom in and use a "clone" tool).